# unresolved external symbol with no "referenced in" field

Tags: c++, linker-errors, extern

So, usually when you see an Unresolved External Symbol error, the linker at least tells you what function the reference is in, i.e.

`unresolved external symbol "class1::function1" **referenced in function "class2::function2"**`

But what do you do when you only get the first half? i.e.

`unresolved external symbol "class1::function1"`

I know where "class1::function1" is defined, and I am deliberately not including it.  So just including the file containing the definition won't help.  The include is ifdef'd out, along with all references to symbols contained in the file.  What I need is a way to locate the reference to this deliberately non-included symbol so that I can get rid of it.  Searches for the name of the symbol reveal only things which I have already ifdef'd out.

Comment: Is it a virtual function?

Comment: Yes, should have included that before.  the full error signature is 

`unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall class1::function1"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to have been a combination of a mistake on my part, and a non-helpful error message.  **One of the classes was missing a member of it's inheritance chain.**

Personally I would have expected this to result in a compiler error ("Extending Undefined Base Class" or something similar), but instead I got linker errors for the virtual functions in said base class (despite that class not being included).  But because no functions were actually referencing them, the linker could not provide a "referenced in" section for the error message.  I still don't entirely understand why this set of problems with the code gave that set of error messages, but I was able to fix it.

Thank you Alan for your input, it got me looking in the correct direction.  I would upvote you, but having joined immediately before posting the question, I lack the reputation score to do so.

Comment: It's a variant of what I said - the derived class constructors also need a reference to the vtable, and hence virtual functions, of the base class. (The linker doesn't much know about classes, just functions and variables.)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a virtual function then it's referenced from the vtable, which in turn is referenced from each constructor (or each place where a constructor is inlined).

If you're using instances of the class I think your best bet is to remove the virtual keyword. Otherwise you must provide a definition, even if only a stub.

(The language standard handles this by considering any virtual function as always used, so a definition is required.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why that happens, but easy way to determine source of problem is to comment out all declarations of class1::function1, and rebuild the project - compiler will complain whenever class1::function1 is called on compile stage instead of linking.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have just tried that, and it makes no difference.  It makes it through compilation just fine, and then still gets the same linker error.

Comment: @jbcarpen, This sounds interesting, is it possible that something does not get rebuild? In that case it will try to link against some old object that does not correspond to current code, and is omitted at compilation stage because it has its date in the future, or is not included as source but as library dependency only?

Comment: Just tried with a completely clean build, and still no change.